# Local notification in Android with Corona

Tags: notifications, coronasdk

I am trying to create 3 notifications with 10 seconds gap. However, It only plays the first sound and it repeats forever with 10 seconds gap. Can you please examine my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
local futureTime = 10  --10 seconds 
local sounds =  {"Icebaby.mp3", "Pokemon.mp3", "Yoshi.mp3"}
i=1

local options = {
 alert = "Wake up!",
 sound = "Icebaby.mp3" ,
 custom = { msg = "Alarm" }
}

local notificationID = system.scheduleNotification( futureTime, options )

local function notificationListener( event )

system.cancelNotification(notificationID)
i=i+1
options.sound=sounds[i]
    if(i>3) then
    Runtime:removeEventListener ( "notification", notificationListener )

    else 
        notificationID = system.scheduleNotification( futureTime, options )
    end
end


Runtime:addEventListener( "notification", notificationListener )
```

Comment: Did you try to print out i value? So you can see if something is wrong with it. As I can see it's a global and can be manupulated from outside.

Comment: I made it local and tested that but now it only plays last sound in the table. Did you test the code on your device?

Comment: I can't test on device right now, but can you please use some print() functions to trace the code? You should use them in if else block

Comment: Well, notification doesn't work in simulator, print() is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1st problem: "It only plays the first sound"
-> Yes, because you don't change the options table. So it's always this options table:

```
local options = {
 alert = "Wake up!",
 sound = "Icebaby.mp3" ,
 custom = { msg = "Alarm" }
}
```

Change the options table each time you create the next notification. For example use your "sounds" table!

Comment: I do change it inside notificationListener function : options.sound=sounds[i]

Comment: You do, but you don't use sounds[i] anywhere.

Comment: Again, inside notificationListener's else condition, after updating sound inside options table, I am creating another notification with options parameter. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part